# How can I improve the ActivityManager loading time of my app?

Tags: java, android, optimization, android-activity

I've written an app which processes a lot of data on startup; first startup time of the app is rather slow, but so are subsequent launches.

I previously thought that the relatively un-responsive startup times (~7 seconds) were due to data processing on first load - a bit of debugging suggested about 2 seconds to cold-load. So I redesigned my data structures so they're easier to serialize to persistent storage in between launches (so it caches stuff) and it now saves state when the app finishes in about 20ms, and loading time is about 10-20ms. Much better. (p.s. it's not using the built-in Java serialization, as the state files are now so simple it's easier to save in a plain, human-readable (and editable) text file - it's still pretty quick at reloading from this though!)

However, I'm still finding that the app startup time is about 5 seconds - I've looked in aLogCat which has an entry:

```
I/ActivityManager(...) blah blah blah: +5s193ms
```

So more than 5 seconds to load a relatively simple layout (a few nested LinearLayouts, and a few TextViews - nothing special, and no images) - admittedly that time goes down with subsequent launches (I close the app and open it again, it's ~700ms; rinse and repeat for similar results).

Soooo my question is: how can I improve the app loading times? I'm happy that *first* load takes a little while to process everything - that's fine. But is there a way I can keep the thing in memory, or at least get it into a restorable state so whatever ActivityManager is doing doesn't take so long? I'd like it to be something I can open (probably bound to long-hold search or similar), do whatever, and close it again - thus it needs to open quickly!

Thanks in advance :)

Seb

Comment: Thank you for your responses - I'm now using ASyncTasks for the grunt work which seems to be perfect for things that take too long - and I've left my UI thread light :)

Comment: I also found "traceview" and found out exactly where the bottlenecks were (an amazingly useful tool!) and squished them too...

Comment: As an aside, I also found by using the traceview thing that Html.fromHtml is very expensive. Significantly more so (from what I can see) than setting the text size directly... so removed those too and it's flying along now! Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your heavy-duty start-up work in a background thread that you launch in `onCreate`. (An [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is good for this.) Design your UI to show something meaningful (at least an indeterminate progress bar) when there is no data. When the data is loaded, post a Runnable (or implement `onPostExecute` in your AsyncTask) to update the UI to the real thing.

Comment: This is perfect - and is what I'm doing now - ASyncTasks seem pretty powerful, and well suited to the job. 

One query I do have though is about "Looper" - I had to call Looper.prepare() at the beginning of the doInBackground to make the onPostExecute function not crash my app - haven't found any particularly clear definition of why though...

Comment: on the method onPostExecute of the class you can update the UI with out need of launch a Runnnable.

Answer (score 0):

As Ted suggests, do only the minimum on the UI thread. Five seconds to load the layout is too much, which means that there is some start up method that requires a long time (maybe querying databases, or accessing the net, to populate a long ListView?).

If that processing is absolutely required, then use a splash screen (with a "Please wait while loading data" or similar label).

Answer (score 0):

Divide the work using Asyntasks classes. If you have some data which is always the same store it in database for example to have quickest access next time you open the application, and update that content from time to time.